# ASP.Net Core Integration testing failing due to webapp startup using reklative folder path

Tags: c#, integration-testing, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit, asp.net-core-3.1

I am completely new to integration testing in asp.net core.
I have a asp.net core webapi and trying to setup integration testing for this api project.
When i try to run the basic test it fails due to the following in the configure method inside startup.cs:

```
RegisterExcelTemplate(app, "Upload/ExposureRating/Global/Template/", "/api/upload/exposureRating/global");

private static void RegisterExcelTemplate(IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder, string relativeFolderPath, string apiPath)
{
    applicationBuilder.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), relativeFolderPath)),
        RequestPath = new PathString(apiPath),
        EnableDirectoryBrowsing = false
    });
}
```

When i run the test, getting the following error message:

[image: This is the error while creating httpClient object]

Can anyone help how to fix the folder path issue in test project?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**[Serve files outside of web root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#serve-files-outside-of-web-root)**

You need to create Folders `Upload/ExposureRating/Global/Template/`.
I added a `helloworld.jpg` to test.

[image]

> Screenshots of test

[image]